# The chord length of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

Given an ellipse with semi major axis $a$ and semi minor axis $b$. What is the formula to compute the chord length formed by two points, say $P$ and $Q$ on the arc of the ellipse (Euclidean distance between the two points).

Comment: "the arc length between this two points subtend an angle α" - this is a bit unclear. How does one have a subtended angle in an ellipse?

Comment: The problem has been rephrased.

Answer (score 2):

The parametric equation for the ellipse are $(x,y)=(a \cos \theta, b \sin \theta)$ and the length of the arc between two points $P$ and $Q$ is:
$$
l_{PQ}=\int_{\theta _P}^{\theta_Q}\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\int_{\theta _P}^{\theta_Q}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d \theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d \theta}\right)^2} d \theta =
$$
$$
=\int_{\theta _P}^{\theta_Q}\sqrt{a^2\cos^2 \theta +b^2 \sin^2 \theta} d \theta 
$$

where $\theta_P$ and $\theta _Q$ are the angle from the $x$ axis and the lines that passes thorough the origin and the two points (note that the angle that subtend the arc is not sufficient to fix its length).

This  cannot be evaluated with standard functions, it is an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the  second kind.

For the length of the chord the result is simpler:

$$
L=\sqrt{(x_P-x_Q)^2+(y_P-y_Q)^2}=\sqrt{a^2(\cos \theta_P-\cos \theta_Q)^2+b^2(\sin \theta_P-\sin \theta_Q)^2}
$$
but also in this case we need two angles.

Comment: Thanks  for your help. I am however interested in the chord length (the Euclidean distance between the two points).

Comment: AH..AH.. OK! I edit  and add :)

Comment: If need be, one can use the [prosthaphaeresis formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) on the chord length expression.